# Interacting with Reporting services with C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Is there an API or interop for interacting with Reporting Services 2005/2008 from .Net or in particular C#?

The reason is we have some business logic for our row-level security in our application server, and would like our application server to work with the reporting services.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

I found this link, which gives a brief explanation of the architecture for connecting to reporting services web services, does anyone have any more light they could shed?

http://en.csharp-online.net/Reporting_Services_Architecture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Reporting Services has a web service under `http://server/reportserver` with a rich API

You can also use the ReportViewer control in your app

In general, you should look at this page ["Reporting Services Programming"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The Reporting Services Programming web page has been updated to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522713.aspx for newer versions of SQL Server.